# NG8001: 'mat-table' is not a known element:

Tags: angular-material, mat-table, angular11

I am trying to adapt the following
[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-inline-editing-5bpdja?file=app%2Ftable-editing-example.ts)

which works fine. But in my Angular 11 application I ma getting:

```
 error NG8001: 'mat-table' is not a known element
```

I am using the exact same code that I have placed inside of the shared module. In the shared module I have added the following:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    MatTableModule
],
...
exports: [
    MatTableModule
]
```

Still, it's not working. Any adea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you add `SharedModule` to `imports` of `AppModule` or your root module?

Comment: Yes, it's there